# Apply css to DIV only if it contains data

Tags: html, css, asp.net, padding

So for example the MainContent_lockedOutError div does not contain data between the div tags

```
<div id="MainContent_LockedOutError" class="failureNotification" style="text-align:left"></div>
```

...But say a I have a list...

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>Text 1</i>
<ii>Text 2</ii>
</ul>
</div>
```

So im not sure if this is possible but in my css can I add

`div
{
    padding:0.7%;
}`

only if the div has data...which adds padding to the div containing the list but not the MainContent_lockedOutError div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use a combination of `:not()` and `:empty`

```
div:not(:empty) {
    padding:0.7%;
}
```

This will add the rule only if a div is NOT empty like it is for `#MainContent_lockedOutError` example.

It's slightly fragile though because if there is even a space between the opening/closing tag it won't work. Maybe it can work for you.

Comment: Jolly Good old chap! ...thanks for the quick response